# Having player names over models in 3d space

Tags: unity

I wanted to have in my multiplayer game, the players name's over their models, however I am faced with the question of how? Should I create a new Canvas object for each game model or just use 1 main canvas and move their names around relative to position in 3D world space? My aim is to have an open world game.

Comment: Looks like you have two possible ways to do this. What did you try and what were the results?

Comment: I tried to get each player instance with a canvas, but then I wonder about performance when there are many players in the same zone, and the other option I am not sure how to calculate the screen coordinates for players in the camera range.

Comment: This highlights 2 things: you'll need a way to simulate a high number of players to test performance; if you don't know how to convert world coordinates into screen coordinates, you might want to search about this or ask a question asking this instead :)

Comment: True, but also i wanted to have an opinion of some more experienced devs as to the option which offers better performance too.

Comment: Here is a similar question/answer about the performance - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52710442/single-canvas-and-multiple-panels-vs-multiple-canvas-in-unity-3d/

Comment: @Nikaas I see, need to watch more Unite talks than I normally do hehe